# AJAX GET request works only after pressing back and trying again

Tags: jquery, ajax, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I have the weirdest bug that I do not understand. I am using Spring Boot with thymeleaf and have an AJAX GET request.

Basically, I am making a REST search service that uses String parameter to query mongoDB. My REST API works fine, I can query anything I want, however the issue starts if I want to use my search REST API via the search box on results page.

When I press "Search" on the search box, my request is being sent, but I am being redirected to "Bad Request 400 - Required String parameter 'searchQuery' is not present". However, when I press back button in browser and type any query, the one that did not previously work is sent instead. Is my AJAX request incorrect, is there something to do with the way Thymeleaf works or other magic?

This is my AJAX request:

```
 var searchQuery = document.getElementById("search_input").value;

            function doAjax() {
                $.ajax({
                    url: "/search",
                    type: 'GET',
                    data: {
                        searchQuery: searchQuery
                    }
                }).success(function (data) {
                        window.location.href = "/search?searchQuery=" + searchQuery;
                });

                alert("yay2");
            }
```

And this is my HTML:

```
  <form>
       <label for="search_input">Search:</label>
       <input type="text" id="search_input"></input>
       <button onclick="doAjax()">GO</button>
   </form>
```

This is exactly what happens (I may not be explaining myself clearly as I am a beginner): [SEE THIS GIF I MADE](https://giphy.com/gifs/3oEjI6VFaBR1M6xEhG)

Comment: I see that it's losing the `searchQuery` value... Is there anything else wired up on the button?  How about this... can you try a `return false;` after your `alert("yay2")` to stop bubbling and prevent form submission?  My guess is that it's submitting the form. You can pass the click event args into the doAjax and call `evt.preventDefault();` to see if that's sufficient but your button isn't if type submit so it baffles me too.  If you can't copy this code into a plunker and reproduce it, my guess is that something else on the page is affecting it.

Comment: Thank you so much for your comment, really appreciate it! The suggestion Voyta gave worked perfectly - such little things and such a problem! :) And you were right about submit - it was the default behaviour!

Comment: My pleasure.  There's one advantage to keeping the button of type submit and using `evt.preventDefault();` instead of changing the type to `button`. If you keep it of type submit, then the user can hit enter with the textbox having focus and it'll submit the button.  I usually wire up my events on the form submit event instead that way I can have validation fire.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

2 things:

1. You need to put `var searchQuery = document.getElementById("search_input").value;` inside the doAjax() function. Right now it gets the value only once - on page load.
2. You need to prevent button default action - submitting the form. E.g. `<button onclick="doAjax();" type="button">GO</button>` (type="submit" is default if type is not specified and will submit the form, type="button" will not.

   ```
       function doAjax() {
           var searchQuery = document.getElementById("search_input").value;
           $.ajax({
               url: "/search",
               type: 'GET',
               data: {
                   searchQuery: searchQuery
               }
           }).success(function (data) {
                   window.location.href = "/search?searchQuery=" + searchQuery;
           });

           alert("yay2");
       }
   ```

HTML:

```
<form>
   <label for="search_input">Search:</label>
   <input type="text" id="search_input"></input>
   <button onclick="doAjax()" type="button">GO</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Oh my goodness, thank you so much!! It works perfectly! I did not know it was getting the value only once - but it does make perfect sense. Really appreciate your help :)